# Images from Fantart.tv not showing up in my emby media server

Tags: windows, dns

Found this error in the Emby logs.
`System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: The requested address is not valid in its context. (webservice.fanart.tv:443)`
Four days ago I asked this question on the Emby forums but no answer.
This just started 4 days ago randomly.

**I tried the following**

1. Restarted the computer the emby server runs on.
2. Restarted the emby server.
3. Flushed my dns cache in cmd.
4. Don't use a vpn.

I'm trying to avoid re-installing emby.

Comment: Have you try to change your DNS server ?

Comment: Before you go down the path of thinking it is emby, try to connect to webservice.fanart.tv port 443 with a telnet client.  What happens?

Comment: @S.Brottes how?

Comment: sen webservice.fanart.tv port 443
Not Connected @SeñorCMasMas not sure i did it right

Comment: Microsoft Telnet> o webservice.fanart.tv 443
Connecting To webservice.fanart.tv...

Connection to host lost. @SeñorCMasMas. seems i cant get a connection

Comment: i tried again with my vpn off `Microsoft Telnet> o webservice.fanart.tv 443
Connecting To webservice.fanart.tv...Could not open connection to the host, on port 443: Connect failed`

Comment: If telnet can't do it, it has nothing to do with your emby server :) AND you learned a cool new trick.  You might try making sure the DNS lookup happened correctly as @S.Brottes indicated.. if you can find the IP address of `webservice.fanart.tv`, you can again use the telnet command with IP address to determine if the problem is DNS or not.

Comment: `Tracing route to webservice.fanart.tv [91.134.1.171]
over a maximum of 30 hops:

  1  .hsd1.wv.comcast.net [10.0.0.178]  reports: Destination host unreachable.` but its reachable for everyone but me?                                        `Microsoft Telnet> o 10.0.0.186 443
Connecting To 10.0.0.186...Could not open connection to the host, on port 443: Connect failed`

Comment: I also tried changing the dns to cloud fronts but did not fix my problem @SeñorCMasMas

Comment: how to  make sure the DNS lookup happened correctly?

Comment: You can use DNS client like nslookup

Comment: ill try it tomorrow. But fanart.tv works in jellyfin? so I'm stumped. @S.Brottes

Comment: I can open fanart.tv from South America. You could test some free VPN to locate you in other country and try again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem. It was the split tunnel. I had three Emby exes split away from the tunnel. Even if the vpn was off the split tunnel stayed. So I put the exes back in the tunnel and it solved the problem.